# http://localhost/ReportServer/ no setting to add role - permissions granted to user are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

Installed Report Server 2017. Running native mode with credentails: NT Service\SQLServerReportingServices account. My user is in the local admin group adn still get the below error. Problem is there is no settings icon for me to add roles. Where can I start to add any needed roles?

http://localhost/ReportServer/

> The permissions granted to user 'domain\user' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Comment: But did you add your User Account as an Admin for SSRS when you installed it (the answer is very likely "no"). If so, you'll need to launch Internet Explorer/Edge (**not** Chrome/Firefox/Safari/etc) as the local administrator on the host that SSRS is installed on and access the URL. Then you'll have to add your domain (not domian) user as an Administrator on the SSRS portal.

Comment: I've launched IE as administrator and from http://localhost/ReportServer/ , I'm expecting a settings icon in the upper write where I can add the user as an Administrator. No settings icon to work with.

Comment: You want http://localhost/Reports not http://localhost/ReportServer. The former is the administration portal, the latter is the report browser.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful suggestions. I'm not quite sure what fixed it because I also uninstalled and re-installed (this time installed running as local administrator) and it's up and running. I definitely benefited from your input.